# Linux Libertine Initials break emph

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, libertine

Loading the Linux Libertine Initials font breaks the `emph` command, even if the font is not used:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}                                                        

\usepackage{fontspec}                                                           
\usepackage{xunicode}                                                           
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}                               
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont{Linux Libertine Initials O}                         

\begin{document}                                                             

This is a test with \emph{emphasis}.                                            


\end{document}
```

gives

[image: emph bug]

Is this known? How can it be prevented (other than redefining `emph` to use Linux Libertine Slanted)?

Comment: You should mention that you use/this needs XeLaTeX.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. I suspect that different fonts are used from XeTeX and xdvipdfmx.

Comment: Funny, I have the full TeXLive 2010 installation but the font is not included. How did you installed it exactly?

Comment: @Raphink: This is 'works for me' with a fresh Linux Libertine download. Either the font or TeX system is suspect: perhaps a `\listfiles` output plus version information on your font would be helpful.

Comment: @Martin, @Joseph: I got the otf files from http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=91&L=1 .

Comment: Note that it happens with both TL2010 (installed manually) and TL2009 (installed with Ubuntu packages).

Comment: @Raphink: Yes, the source is clear, but what about the _version_ (I have 5.1.3).

Comment: @Joseph: I have 5.1.3, too, and an up-to-date TL2010 install (`tlmgr update --all` says there's nothing to update).

Comment: When fonts go mad it is - as egreg mentioned - often due to multiple version of fonts. So at first check them: Put `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` at the begin of your file. Then compile in a command window with `xelatex --outputdriver="xdvipdfmx -vv" file` then compare carefully in log and the messages of xdvipdfmx the pathes of the fonts used. If you can't find the reason: Add also `\listfiles` to the .tex and show us the log-file of the compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I had the `ttf-linux-libertine` package installed, which was conflicting with my local fonts. After removing this package, all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to avoid corruption is to define the font with full path in the `.tex` file or remove the relevant entries in `/etc/fonts`.