# \emph yields bold-italic using the package "libertine"

Tags: xetex, italic, libertine, emphasis

How can I make `\emph` use italics again after loading the package `libertine`? I suspect that this may be a bug in the font itself. I tried reinstalling the font and upgrading it onto the most recent version. I am using XeTeX and Linux. (Ubuntu)

Comment: The font seems to have issues, see [Linux Libertine Initials break emph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21944/linux-libertine-initials-break-emph), which is basically a duplicate, right?

Comment: I found the solution. This was a bug and is fixed by now.

Comment: Feel free to post the solution as answer by yourself. Other people might have the same issue. Otherwise please delete the question. Either way, it should not stay unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a bug in the font. Upgrading the font to 5.1.3 and removing the old font files solves the problem.

Comment: Don't forget you can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) after a waiting period of 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

i wonder if you're using the proper encoding: libertine fonts are only available in T1 encoding (under ordinary latex, anyway).  The following works for me

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
...
\begin{document}
here \emph{we} \textbf{are \emph{again}}
...
```

Comment: FUZxxl uses xetex which use the open type version of the fonts and fontspec (and so encoding EU1).